# Некорректная передача параметров в URI

Tags: java, java-ee, rest, кодировка, jax-rs

Внимание! Можете не напрягаться над решением, просто подскажите в каком направлении думать!

Имеем очень простой сервис:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/search")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getSubscriber(@QueryParam("data") SubscriberSearchFormData data){   
        System.out.println(data);
        List <SubscrEntity> results = null  //list of results
        return Response.ok(results).build();
    }
```

Класс SubscriberSearchFormData:

```
public class SubscriberSearchFormData {
    private String name;
    private String street;
    private Integer contractNumber;

    public static SubscriberSearchFormData fromString(String jsonRepresentation) throws Exception { 
          System.out.println("WE ARE HERE");
          ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // Jackson's JSON marshaller
          SubscriberSearchFormData obj = null;
          try {
           obj = mapper.readValue(decoded, SubscriberSearchFormData.class);
          } catch (IOException e) {
           throw new Exception("Wrong JSON parameters!");
          }
          return obj;
    }

    //all getters and setters
}
```

По задумке, JSON должен автоматически парситься благодаря методу fromString в объект класса SubscriberSearchFormData. И с ним дальше будем работать. Но как только я вызываю сервис:

```
localhost:8080/application/rest/catalog/subscriber/search?data={
"name":"bbb",
"street":"eee",
"contractNumber":5
}
```

Всё падает из-за ошибки:

```
11:24:04,050 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-3) RESTEASY002130:
Failed to parse request.: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilderException: RESTEASY003330: 
Failed to create URI: http://localhost:8080/application/rest/catalog/subscriber/search?data={%20%22name%22:%22bbb%22,%20%22street%22:%22eee%22,%20%22contractNumber%22:%225%22}
```

И при этом,  `System.out.println("WE ARE HERE");` даже не вызывается. То есть оно рушится, ещё даже до вызова `fromString();`

Копаюсь в этом второй день и всё ничего не удаётся решить.

Comment: А почему нельзя передать JSON в теле запроса?
Зачем передавать его как параметр, тем самым превращая ссылку в не валидную.

Comment: @MoS1993 Вы не могли бы объяснить поподробнее, что вы имеете в виду? В теле запроса, т.е. как POST?

Comment: а метод `fromString` должен бросать `Exception` ?

Comment: @MrFylypenko Конечно должен

`try {
     obj = mapper.readValue(...);
    } catch (IOException e) {
     throw new Exception("Wrong JSON parameters!");
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите себе для браузера Chrome расширение - Postman, которое поможет в работе с HTTP запросами.

Реализуйте метод таким образом:

```
@POST
@Path("/search")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getSubscriber(SubscriberSearchFormData data) {
    System.out.println(data);
    List <SubscrEntity> results = null  //list of results
    return Response.ok(results).build();
}
```

Классу `SubscriberSearchFormData` необходимо добавить конструктор по умолчанию и Getters/Setters.

Далее отправьте POST запрос на сервер:
[image]

И в методе получите ваш объект.

Comment: Отлично! Я с удовольствием принимаю ваш ответ. Но прежде скажите: нет ли возможности совершать аналогичное, но всё-таки с гет-запросом?

Уж очень нужно именно через гет.

Comment: А почему конкретно GET?
По названию URL, подразумевается, что будет POST, т.к. вы говорите серверу: "найди мне подписчиков по заданным параметрам"!
Если я не ошибаюсь, то GET запрос можно тоже с телом делать.

Comment: Нет, не согласен с Вами. POST-запрос служит для отправки каких-то данных на сервер, как правило, в один конец. Например, отправка формы с анкетой пользователя. А в моём случае, это поиск. Найти и получить. И соответственно, семантически верным будет использовать GET-запрос.

Но в любом случае, большое спасибо Вам!